# Excel Pivot Table Calculated Field - Sum & Average Results Not Correct

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I've created a basic pivot table from a large data set. I am have a SUM on several values and an AVERAGE on a single value.

For the average value, I need to divide the sum's against it, to get a %, but when I try to do this in a calculated field, the results are not correct.  Below is an example of my data:

### Rep Name|Sum|Call Avg

Rep 1|96|817

Rep 2|69|547

Rep 3|119|595

Rep 4|141|853

What I am hoping to divide is 96/817, for example, to get roughly 11.75%.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I am missing?

P.S. Sorry for the horrible formatting, long time searcher, first time poster.

Answer (score 0):

I added a helper column, there is no way around this since the calculated field cannot average, only sum.  I did not know it could not average when I asked the question.

I appreciate Anjcastles time.